# MediaPlayer and threading cleanup before onBackPressed

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I have a mediaplayer in my activity and with the mediaplayer I have a seekbar that I am updating via a thread handler. The way I run the thread handler is like so:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };

    public void seekUpdation() {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            this.seekbar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            this.seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 2);
        }
    }
```

I call this whenever the user hits the play button and then the seekbar keeps getting updated while the mediaplayer is in playing. SO this works great, but when I hit the Back button when the mediaplayer is playing I then get an illegalstateexception because I am doing the following:
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

```
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mr != null)
        mr.release();
    if (mp != null){
        mp.pause();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

See I figured by pausing the mediaplayer this would trigger the thread to stop, but it hasn't worked. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: try to stop first then release player buddy

Comment: like this 
mp.stop();
mp.release();

Comment: @kamalvaid I tried this but it still doesn't work... it's like the thread is not getting the signal that the player is not still running before it is then released.

Comment: I don't know what the repercussions of not releasing the mediaplayer, but when I take out the mp.release() then it seems to work fine. What could be my drawbacks?